# How to create in Terraform Azure PolicyDefinition with local JSON-file?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create an Azure PolicyDefinition and I am using the code below:

```
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "name-caf-alz-policy-sandbox-denyvnetpeering" {
  name                = "Audit-AzureHybridBenefit"
  display_name        = "Unused resources driving cost should be avoided"
  description         = "Optimize cost by enabling Azure Hybrid Benefit. Leverage this Policy definition as a cost control to reveal Virtual Machines not using AHUB."
  mode                = "All"
  policy_type         = "Custom"                                           
  policy_rule         = file("${path.module}/lib/policy_definitions/policy_definition_es_deny_vnet_peer_cross_sub.json")
  management_group_id = data.azurerm_management_group.namemgmtgroup.id
}
```

When I run this command via Azure DevOps, Terraform Validate, Init, and Plan are working but when I do Terraform Apply I get this error:

**creating/updating Policy Definition "Audit-AzureHybridBenefit": policy.DefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdateAtManagementGroup: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidPolicyRule" Message="Failed to parse policy rule: 'Could not find member 'apiVersion' on object of type 'PolicyRuleDefinition'. Path 'apiVersion'.'."**

When I change the `policy_rule` to

`jsonencode(file("${path.module}/lib/policy_definitions/policy_definition_es_deny_vnet_peer_cross_sub.json"))`

**Error: expanding JSON for policy_rule: JSON: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}**

The JSON-file itself works succesfully when creating it via the GUI.

JSON-file itself can be found at

https://github.com/Azure/Enterprise-Scale/blob/main/src/resources/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Deny-VNET-Peer-Cross-Sub.json

Comment: Why do you extra parenthesis around the `file`? This is probably not the cause of the issue, but they are unnecessary.

Comment: Because it said so in the Terraform Wiki
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/file

Comment: The docs do not say about any extra parenthesis.

Comment: I see what you mean. It should be only one time. This was a typo since I was also experimenting with the jsonencode function.

Comment: If it is failing continuously in the above way, you can pass the raw `json` context to the policy rule in the `main.tf` file itself. I tried in that way and worked for me. @Xyltic

Comment: Could you elaborate further with what you're saying @Jahnavi ? Do you mean that I copy the JSON-content and paste it inside the main.tf file and then rerun the code?

Comment: I've given clearly in the answer. Can you please check. @Xyltic

Comment: Yes you need to copy the Json policy rule content and give directly in the `main.tf` file. @Xyltic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue indicates that the `Apiversion` property, which is present in the `Json file` path you provided, is incompatible. The [Structure of Policy defintion Json](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure.md) as specified in this Doc should not always include the `apiversion` property.

To verify the issue properly, I've tried adding the `Json` policy in the `policy rule` of `.tf` file and it worked as expected as shown.

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "name-caf-alz-policy-sandbox-denyvnetpeering" {
  name                = "Audit-AzureHybridBenefit"
  display_name        = "Unused resources driving cost should be avoided"
  description         = "Optimize cost by enabling Azure Hybrid Benefit. Leverage this Policy definition as a cost control to reveal Virtual Machines not using AHUB."
  mode                = "All"
  policy_type         = "Custom"                                           
  policy_rule         = <<POLICY_RULE
  {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/remoteVirtualNetwork.id",
            "notcontains": "[[subscription().id]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    }
    POLICY_RULE   
  }
```

As you are not using `parameters` in the Policy, I have not included the `parameters` block below. If required, you may add it to the `policyrule` with the following structure to make it work.

```bash
parameters =  <<PARAMETERS
     {
     "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "Audit",
          "Deny",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "Deny"
      }
    }
    PARAMETERS
```

***Executed*** `terraform init` ***and validated the configuration using*** `terraform validate`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply`:

[image]

***Created policy definition successfully in the Portal:***

[image]

*Or*

if you only want to work with `file(path)` function, you don't need to include `jsonencode` function because the `policy_rule` input to the `azurerm_policy_definition` resource should be a `map` representing the `JSON` structure, not a `string`. Make sure the syntax and path has correctly given.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I've tried it myself and it works. I just did not understand it very well with the official documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_definition

Just from your expert knowledge: Let say that you have to create multiple policy definitions in Terraform. Each of these terraform code will have approxmatiely 80+ lines of codes which is not nice to see. What do you suggest to do this much cleaner?

Create a JSON-file with only policy_rule / parameters / metadata code and refer it all in 1 file?

Comment: Yep exactly. Just create a file which contains only policy rule and parameters if required. @Xyltic

Comment: Do you have an example how this should be done? What needs to be filled in the JSON-file specifically and should I fill the map command as here below:

`policy_rule = map(file("${path.module}/lib/policy_definitions/policy_definition_es_deny_vnet_peer_cross_sub.json"))`  Because from an infra-engineer like myself, I've tried this by myself but it's not working. I am also willing to donate a cup of coffee to you for your appreciation and work.

Comment: By following the schema structure which I've already provided you in the above answer, you can achieve that. And no need to use any `map ()` or something. Just pass `jsondecode(file(..))`. @Xyltic

Comment: Cheers fo the explanation.